# Is there a tool to visualize make files like POM dependency graphs?

Tags: android

I am trying to understand AOSP makefiles, I am lost following the build structure. It's way too complex. Is there any tool that gives the build process for a target visually or atleast an editor that helps me navigate the build files by clicking on it (Ctrl + Click navigation)

Thanks

Comment: The AOSP build system is based upon the philosophy outlined in [this paper](http://aegis.sourceforge.net/auug97.pdf). Reading this may help your understanding.

Answer (score 0):

No, there are no tools for this. But there are some rules for Android.mk files. The Android build system start to look for Android.mk files recursively: starting from more "root" folders and proceeding to more far folders. Maybe this can help you to understand build files.